# Run function after modal dismissed in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I want to call a function on a view controller after a modal has been dismissed. I have spent hours trying to get this to work and all of the responses I have found have not worked. I have followed instructions by others and set up a protocol but this still isn't working.

MainController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, loadStoreDelegate{
```

Then to trigger the modal I use

```
func displaySelectStorePopup(){
        if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SelectStoreView"){
            let selectStoreController = viewController
            selectStoreController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
            if let sctrl = selectStoreController.popoverPresentationController{
                sctrl.delegate = self
                sctrl.sourceView = self.view
                sctrl.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds),0,0)

                sctrl.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection()
                delay(0.1){
                    sctrl.passthroughViews = nil
                }

                selectStoreController.modalInPopover = true

                selectStoreController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 400)

                self.presentViewController(selectStoreController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then the function id like to use

```
func loadStore() {
        print(2)
        //let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardView")
        //self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)
    }
```

ModalViewController:
The protocol

```
protocol loadStoreDelegate{
    func loadStore()
}

class SelectStoreViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{...

var delegate: loadStoreDelegate?
```

Then call the function on tableview click

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        self.delegate?.loadStore()
        if(tableView == selectStoreTable){
            currentStore = userStores[indexPath.row]
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are calling `loadStore()` _before_ calling `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)`. So that is not "after it has been dismissed".

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to see what is happening?

Comment: Yes I get a nil value from the delegate

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your `prepareForSegue` and step through.  It isn't doing what you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Your SelectStoreViewController class has a `delegate` instance property. But you are never setting this property to anything. So it is `nil` when you `self.delegate?.loadStore()`. So naturally nothing happens.

I think you want something like this:

```
func displaySelectStorePopup(){
    if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SelectStoreView") as? SelectStoreViewController {
        let selectStoreController = viewController
        selectStoreController.delegate = self // *
        // ... and so on ...
```

Comment: In all the examples I have seen this is how they are referencing the delegate? What do I set it to?

Comment: To the ViewController instance. That is who you are trying to have as your delegate (the `loadStoreDelegate`). Your question is not very clear but I've added some code that shows what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: when I try this the selectStoreController has no delegate method so I cannot set it. the ctrl variable does have a delegate method but that isn't solving the problem either

Comment: See my revised code. You have to tell the compiler that `viewController` is a SelectStoreViewController.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading it seems that using the popover is what is preventing my desired results from the delegate. I ended up solving this by creating a class for the workstation that holds a reference to the current view, then a function that runs the action I needed.

Class:

```
class Workstation{
    var currentView: UIViewController? = nil
    var currentStore : Store? = nil

    func loadInStore(store: Store){
        currentStore = store
        if let view = currentView{
            let vc : AnyObject! = view.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardView")
            view.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)
        }
    }

    class var workstationInstance: Workstation{
        struct Static {
            static let instance = Workstation()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }
}
```

SecondController:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        if let store = selectedStore{
            Workstation.workstationInstance.loadInStore(store)
        }
    }
```

In my main controller I am simply loading in the popup and setting the current view

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
     Workstation.workstationInstance.currentView = self
}

func displaySelectStorePopup(){
        if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SelectStoreView"){
            let selectStoreController = viewController
            selectStoreController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
            if let sctrl = selectStoreController.popoverPresentationController{
                sctrl.sourceView = self.view
                sctrl.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds),0,0)

                sctrl.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection()
                delay(0.1){
                    sctrl.passthroughViews = nil
                }

                selectStoreController.modalInPopover = true

                selectStoreController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 400)

                self.presentViewController(selectStoreController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```